# Are there mechanics to heal shadowlands?

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

As far as I understand shadowlands occur in places where a great massacre occured and gradually expand, they can be used as gates for creatures of underworld and they give advantages to those creatures. Are there any charms or example spells that cause shadowlands to get smaller or otherwise cease to exist?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

There are a few vague examples of methods of slowing their growth or slowly causing them to fade over decades/centuries (the Traveler's Road to Whitewall and I think a few groups in Chiaroscuro being the best examples) but there are no explicit rules for reclaiming shadowlands.

I believe finding out how to do so is explicitly called out as being a good focus for an exalted campaign or requires developing custom charms but I can't narrow it down a book or page number.